# TTS(Text to speech) for android using server

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am trying Text to speech convertion in android but not locally actually i want pass my text in to server and then server will give me the MP3 file which i have to handle so please any one can tell me how to do that. i very worried about that.

Comment: What's to worry? You'll succeed!

Answer (score 0):

That is not advisable especially if you can do speech synthesis on the phone with an available language. If not then try to find some Java library that can do that for you and then stream that audio.